# Filter HTML table with dropdowns but using button to confirm

Tags: javascript

I have this code that life-filter the table using the dropdowns.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        
            $('.filter').change(function () {
                var values = [];
        
                 $('.filter').each(function () {
                    var colIdx = $(this).data('col');
        
                     $(this).find('option:selected').each(function () {
                         if ($(this).val() != "") values.push( {
                            text: $(this).text(),
                            colId : colIdx
                         });
                    });
                });
                filter('table > tbody > tr', values);
            });
        
            function filter(selector, values) {console.log(values);
                $(selector).each(function () {
                    var sel = $(this);
                    var tokens = sel.text().trim().split('\n');
                    var toknesObj = [], i;
                    for(i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
                        toknesObj[i] = {
                           text:tokens[i].trim(), 
                           found:false
                        };
                    }
        
                    var show = false;
                    //console.log(toknesObj);
                    $.each(values, function (i, val) {                
        
                   if (toknesObj[val.colId].text.search(new RegExp("\\b"+val.text+"\\b")) >= 0) {
                       toknesObj[val.colId].found = true;
                      }
        
                    });          
                    console.log(toknesObj);
                    var count = 0;
                     $.each(toknesObj, function (i, val) {
                         if (val.found){
                             count+=1;
                         }
                     });
                    show = (count === values.length);        
                    show ? sel.show() : sel.hide();
                });
            }
            });
```

I need a modification to use the same code but instead of life-filter, use a Search button to run the filter. Maybe the problem is the `.change(function ()` but i'm not sure how to implement the way to use the search button instead of life-filter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By replacing the selector before the `.change` for a reference of the button and swapping the `.change` for a `.click` might work for your case.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('.button-selector').click(function () {
      ...
  });
  
  ...
});
```